# Am I understanding this correctly? しないと

Tags: translation, particle-と

There is a character, an older male,  in this manga that I'm reading who uses this phrase twice
 しないとな and the two lines are like this：

> 1. お礼をしないとな
> 2. お別れをしないとな

The first line, he is referring to himself (**I** should show my gratitude)-->I understood it more like "It wouldn't do if I don't show my gratitude" "I have/must...(among these ideas). It was more clear when the character said his 2nd line which I interpreted as: Say your goodbyes/Say farewell (note, he was directing this to another character that was with him).

I hope I made sense...What exactly is the usage of と here? What does it express? And does the 1st line sound okay with the interpretations I gave?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This しないと is a omission of しないといけない. It means "must", "have to".

I think you understand it correctly.

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad to hear my interpretation wasn't that off.