# I'd like to understand the pattern "verb+nai+to(+ne)"

Tags: particle-と

In the sentence:

> 掟は ちゃんと教えないとね
> (okite wa chanto oshienai to ne)
> [You must be taught the rules properly.]

I'd like to understand this pattern of using verb-nai-to(-ne). Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Am I understanding this correctly? しないと](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/52627/am-i-understanding-this-correctly-%e3%81%97%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%81%a8)

Comment: That's not "be taught" it's "teach"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to express obligation in Japanese, like *X has to do Y* or *X must do Y* in English, you have to say something like *if X doesn't do Y, it's bad*. The first part of that structure, the *if X doesn't do Y* is expressed by conjugating the verb in three possible ways. One of them is ない + と. For example, 教えないと means *if X doesn't teach*. Then you'd have to add something like いけない or ならない for the second part of the structure, the *it's bad* part. But in colloquial speech it's usually omitted. So saying *I have to go* is exactly the same as *if I don't go*.

[Here](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/must) you have a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> 掟は

as for the code/rule

---

> ちゃんと

properly

---

> 教えないと

Must teach (same as 教えないとだめ/教えないといけない/教えなければいけない etc...). I think this is the issue. **Must** in Japanese can come in various forms.

---

> ね

right?

Full sentence translated might be something like this:
The code must be told properly.

Adjusted the word from "teach" to "told" since it sounds better for me, but we don't know the actual context here.